# how to use php page in apex [salesforce]?

Tags: php, salesforce, apex

I m creating an application in Salesforce which i need to use Apex programming,

i am developing an application in which salesforce uses the data from php page kindly help me how to use php page in apex {salesforce}.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP Request to the concerned page. When you make the request, you can obtain the entire content of that page in an HTTP response. You can then parse the response for anything that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm
Section : Integration and Apex Utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean like you have a PHP page and that same page you need to design in Salesforce for your application right? So for that, you need to create a VFP page in Salesforce which will be the view portion of your page and then you can create an Apex Controller class for the same to perform the functionality whichever you want in it.

You can even use Aura Lightning components but that might a little difficult for you if you are a newcomer. I would prefer you to start with VFP, learn Salesforce and then go to Lightning. Also, you can use LWC it's more of HTML type only. But I highly recommend you to start with VFP only and then upgrade your knowledge and do the same thing in Lightning or LWC.